# Cron not runing a docker container which starts a python script

Tags: python, docker, shell, cron

I have a docker container which loads a python image. I am then running a python script copied to the docker container via a `Dockerfile` like so:

```
docker run --net=host mybuiltimage /bin/bash -c "python src/runscript.py"
```

This command works directly from the terminal. For it to work via cron and output to a log file I did some changes:

```
* * * * * cd /dir/to/dockerfile && /usr/bin/docker run --net=host mybuiltimage /bin/bash -c "python src/runscript.py" >> /dir/to/log/mylog.log 2>&1
```

The change here is that I am  changing directory to the Dockerfile directory and explicitly giving the full path to the docker command.

This cronjob is still not executing. `mylog.log` is not being created in the given directory. **what is wrong with this?**

Comment: Try using docker run with the detached flag (-d)

Comment: still not executing

Comment: Why do you need to cd to a directory with the dockerfile? and why are you referencing a container and not an image when using docker run?

Comment: I am referencing the image built from a Dockerfile `mycontainer` is just a placeholder name I put which is misleading..edited now. Now I realise I do not need to cd into directory. That is just a force of habit from my part since I usually `build` before `run` which does require cd to directory. Still did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be useful to create a script file, say `/dir/to/script/myscript.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/docker run --net=host mybuiltimage /bin/bash -c "python src/runscript.py" >> /dir/to/log/mylog.log 2>&1
```

You should be able to test the script file:

```
$ bash /dir/to/script/myscript.sh
$ cat /dir/to/log/mylog.log
```

Then in the cron file:

```
* * * * * bash /dir/to/script/myscript.sh
```

Comment: This helped me identify the actual issue: bad path to log file. I was not able to get this error directly from a cronjob. This is always helpful as a debug tool moving forward.